# WPF ContextLayoutManager producing two different code paths

Tags: .net, wpf

I wonder if anybody can help me understand what's going on here.

In a complex WPF custom control, a call to ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout() ends up calling the OnRenderSizeChanged method:

```
MyControl.WPF.dll!MyNameSpace.MyControl.OnRenderSizeChanged(System.Windows.SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo) Line 1838  C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireSizeChangedEvents() + 0x6b bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout() + 0x6e2 bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout() + 0x14 bytes
```

Changing the calls to the complex WPF custom control and now the call to ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout() ends up calling the OnRender method:

```
MyControl.WPF.dll!MyNameSpace.MyControl.OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext) Line 1851  C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(System.Windows.Rect finalRect) + 0x606 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout() + 0x22a bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout() + 0x14 bytes
```

I'm looking for somebody to help me understand what this complex WPF control could be doing to cause the ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout() to trace two different code paths. Thank you!

Comment: Layout in WPF has two passes: one for measure, in which elements determine their desired size, and one for arrange, in which elements are given some available size and can then decide how to fill it.  This may be be a result of the control needing to be measured in the first case, and only needing to be arranged in the second.  What happens if you call `InvalidateMeasure()` before calling `UpdateLayout()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first callstack means that your control has arranged and the previous RenderSize differs from the current one.

The second means that something invalidated arrange. It could be several things: measure returned the different desired size, InvalidateArrange was called explicitly or any property that has the FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange flag changed. 
It could be also some more conditions, but I think these are the most common.

I also suggest you to browse the [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationCore/R/3b5d6051030150b9.html) site, it may be helpful.

Comment: That's it - in the second code path InvalidateVisual() was being called. Perfect, thanks!